# regex match string unless followed by #

Tags: regex, postgresql, replace

I'm trying to add a #param to url's I want to add it to all urls that doesn't already have the # to avoid double param. My urls doesn't look like urls they are made up of handlebar parameters.

they can look like following:

```
{{app.url}}
{{root.app.url}}
{{app.url}}#param
{{root.app.url}}#param
```

So I came up with a regex that matches the handlebar tag ({{(root.)?app.url}})

only problem is that when I later uses `regexp_replace(url, '({{(root\.)?app\.url}})', '\1#param')`

my result looks like this:

```
{{app.url}}#param
{{root.app.url}}#param
{{app.url}}#param#param
{{root.app.url}}#param#param
```

One solution I can think of is doing it in two steps, and the 2nd step should look for duplicate #param#param and replace that with single #param.

But it had me wondering if there was a way using regex to exclude the handlebar tags that are followed by # and completely cancel that match?

Here are some examples:
https://regex101.com/r/d3Zyvo/6

Note: this is for use in postgressql update queries. The regex is POSIX/PCRE. I must use regex_replace with back reference since there might be content before and after the hanbdlebar tags, I simply cannot just concatenate the param. (see the link).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a negative lookahead `(?!#)`:

```
({{(root\.)?app\.url}})(?!#)
                       ^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/d3Zyvo/8).

**Details**

- `({{(root\.)?app\.url}})` - Group 1 (later referred to with `\1` from the replacement pattern):

  - `{{` - `{{` substring
  - `(root\.)?` - an optional Group 2 matching 1 or 0 occurrences of `root.`
  - `app\.url}}`  - a literal `app.url}}` substring
- `(?!#)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately  to the right of the current location, there is a `#` char.

See [Table 9-17. Regular Expression Constraints](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CONSTRAINTS-TABLE):

> `(?!re)`  negative lookahead matches at any point where no substring matching re begins (AREs only)

PostgreSQL demo:

```
select regexp_replace('{{app.url}}
{{root.app.url}}
{{app.url}}#param
{{root.app.url}}#param',
                      '({{(root\.)?app\.url}})(?!#)',
                      '\1#param',
                      'g');
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this seem to have done the trick. I'm currently looking through my data to confirm that there is no duplicates.  "?!" specifies that it is a "negative lookahead" ? I can add any regex after "?!" ? -

Comment: Yes, you may add anything after the lookahead. I am still adding to the post.

Comment: Your explanation is very clear, relevant and direct. I wish the average software development documentation was just half as easy to read as yours.